# React State returning old value after waiting for update with Effect hook?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to do something that in my mind is very simple.
I have an array of documents (firebase firestore) and I have a method to fetch From Document with timeStamp A to docuemnt with timeStamp B

In the fetch function that tries to see if the ref id has already been fetched, but the `messages` inside the `fetchUpTo` function never updates. While the one I log in the effect hook, updates as expected.
The top Log is the Inside `fetchUpTo` and the bottom one is the `effect` one.
The logs are from trying to refetch one of the documents present in the bottom log.
[image]

```
const fetchUpTo = (ref: any) => {
    if (isFetching || isAtEnd) {
        return
    };
    if (!messagesSnapShot) {
        return;
    }
    if (messagesSnapShot.size < queryLimit) {
        return;
    }
    let index = messages.findIndex(d => d.id === ref.id)
    if (index !== -1) {
        if (messageRefs.current[index] !== null) {
            scrollToMessage(messageRefs.current[index])
            return;
        }
    }
    setIsFetching(true)
    const lastVisible = messages[0]
    const cQuery = query(collection(fireStore, "scab-chat", chatId, "messages"), orderBy('time', 'desc'), startAfter(lastVisible.data.time), endAt(ref.data.time));
    getDocs(cQuery).then(newDocs => {
        if (newDocs.size < queryLimit) {
            setIsAtEnd(true)
        }
        const newD = newDocs.docs.map(doc => ({
            data: doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
            ref: doc
        }));
        setMessages(s => {
            const f = newD.filter(doc => s.findIndex(d => d.id === doc.id) === -1)
            return [...s, ...f]
        })
    })
}
```

After doing this, I "wait" for the state to update with an Effect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (messages) {
        setIsFetching(false)
    }
}, [messages])
```

The problem is I have this small part of the code

```
let index = messages.findIndex(d => d.id === ref.id)
    if (index !== -1) {
        if (messageRefs.current[index] !== null) {
            scrollToMessage(messageRefs.current[index])
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are the console.log statements, relative to this code? Calling `setMessages` isn't going to change the current `messages` array, just the one on the next render, so if you're logging the old one, then it's expected that it will not have changed.

Comment: They are  being printed after the first fetch. So FETCH -> WAIT FOR EFFECT (The value here is updated correctly) -> STOP FETCH -> TRIGGER FETCH AGAIN -> CONSOLE.LOG

Answer (score 0):

React state will only rerender you app when the function finishes, so you will only check for the updated messages when you call fetchUpTo again. If you need the updated value on the same function call, try using [flushSync](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react-dom/flushSync).

There is a nice video with Dan Abramov trying to achieve the same as you, I will leave it here for reference: https://youtu.be/uqII0AOW1NM?t=2102

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I fixed it kinda, I had to render a diferent component while the isFetchingState was true so

```
if(isFetching){return <Loader/>}
```

and then it worked. I still don't really understand why It didn't work in the first place.